# BIC values in LCA models

Tags: goodness-of-fit, bic, latent-class

I have been reading posts on this forum about how to assess LCA models. One question asked about BIC statistics to assess model fit. The answer said that you shouldn't really worry about the absolute value of any single BIC statistic; the BIC only matters relative to other models. Some seem to argue that you can get different BICs depending on the software program, so the absolute value of the BIC is irrelevant.

But in my case, I am worried about the absolute value of the BIC because it is gigantic! In the worst set of models the BIC is in the 7 million range. But after adding weights and covariates, the lowest BIC I have been able to get is around 2 million. The LCA results make a lot of sense and are quite interesting actually, am I able to  pick a model based on the relatively lower BIC values compared to models with more/fewer classes. The reason why I am worried is because I have seen different conventions for how to publish this part of the LCA results. Some folks do publish the BICs in tables that evaluate class solutions, other articles using LCA do not.

What advice would you offer? Should I exclude any tables including the BICs? What other ways can I improve the model fit?

Comment: "The answer said that you shouldn't really worry about the absolute value of any single BIC statistic; the BIC only matters relative to other models." That's sensible advice as far as I'm concerned. Chances are that you'll see larger absolute values of the BIC with larger sample sizes. Regarding presenting the BIC values, chances are this won't make or break the success of your paper, so I'd do whatever I feel to do (maybe present rounded BIC in thousands) and if a journal wants it differently, they'll tell you.

Comment: Maybe better present the BICs graphically rather than in a table, that makes comparison easier and doesn't focus on the absolute valuers.

Answer (score 1):

> What advice would you offer? Should I exclude any tables including the BICs?

I agree with @Christian Henning that presenting all BICs in a table may be overkill, and that a figure would be better. Though you could always include it in an appendix.

Regarding your other question:

> What other ways can I improve the model fit.

I would recommend the bootstrap likelihood ratio test (BLRT)$^1$ to compare models, as it has been shown to perform better than information criterions (e.g., the AIC and BIC;  see Nylund, Asparouhov, & Asparouhov, 2007 for more information).

$^1$ The BLRT is a parametric bootstrap procedure proposed by McLachlan & Peel (2000) that uses bootstrap samples to estimate the distribution of the log likelihood difference test statistic.

**References**

McLachlan, G., & Peel, D. (2000). Finite mixture models. New York: Wiley

Nylund, K. L., Asparouhov, T., & Asparouhov, B. O. (2007). Deciding on the number of classes in latent class analysis and growth mixture modeling: A Monte Carlo simulation study. Structural equation modeling: A multidisciplinary Journal, 14(4), 535-569.